# History recognition

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to ask for help recognizing a historic event?

More specifically, I remember reading somewhere about an event, but I only recall bits and parts of it - and couldn't find anything in Google or elsewhere.

So is this the place to ask for help "locating" the actual event (and whether any such event indeed occurred)?

Comment: I don't know if there's a policy on this, but personally would prefer such questions to be voiced in Chat instead.

Comment: You could tell us what it is you are looking for here in Meta, and then we could recommend whether or not to ask it in the main site. It really depends on what you ask and how you ask it.

Comment: To expand on Jacob's question, are identification of historical photographs allowed that are not "who is this person" (which would be more genealogical) but what is this place or event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the problematic nature of "events" in historiography, the fact that the questions are poorly formed based on subjective experience (I recall only X Y and Z about something) they are unlikely to make good matches for our question format.  Asking on Chat ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine ) would be a great solution.